# Can I use a VLAN to prevent naming conflicts from devices on the same subnet?

Tags: vlan, switching

My scenario is this...

I have a business where all of the devices are connected to two layer 2 HP switches that are joined by a static port team.  All of the connected devices are on the same IP network and all are in the same VLAN.  Part of the business requires us to build multiple servers with the same image simultaneously but we run into naming conflicts doing this because the new systems that are built are broadcasting the same default name across the network.  If I put each of these server builds on its own VLAN would that resolve the problem? The systems would still need to be able to see the domain server and the internet though, so I'm not sure how to set this up so that they all don't conflict with each other but can all still access the internet.

Comment: What name are you talking about here? hostname? What protocol is used to broadcast the hostname and what problem does it cause?

Answer (score 1):

Yes a vlan would prevent broadcast traffic from hitting a different L2 broadcast domain.

I would modify how the name is assigned as well it sounds like it is hard coded somewhere.